# Как при наведении на svg добиться появления текста

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, vue.js, svg

Как при наведении на svg добиться появления текста

svg

```
<svg width="20" height="12" viewBox="0 0 20 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="20" height="4" fill="white"/>
<rect y="4" width="20" height="4" fill="#001AFF"/>
<rect y="8" width="20" height="4" fill="#FF0000"/>
</svg>
</symbol>
```

vue

```
            <div class="flag flag--ru">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="@/assets/svg/svg.svg#flag-ru"></use>
              </svg>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Для появления текста подсказки при наведении курсора на элементы SVG, обычно используется теги `<title>`, которые должны быть между групповыми тегами `<g>`.
   Так как это внутри  системная функция SVG, то стилизация в этом случае невозможна.  Более широкие возможности возникают при использовании второго способа см. ниже

Наведите курсор на иконку и немного подождите:

```html
<style>
body {
  background-color: #33333f;
}
</style>
<svg width="20" height="12" viewBox="0 0 20 12"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<symbol id="flag-ru">
<rect width="20" height="4" fill="white"/>
<rect y="4" width="20" height="4" fill="#001AFF"/>
<rect y="8" width="20" height="4" fill="#FF0000"/> 
</symbol>
</svg>
<div class="flag flag--ru">
              <svg width="20" height="12" viewBox="0 0 20 12" style="border:1px solid grey"> 
                 <g>
                 <title> Русскоязычная версия сайта </title>
                <use xlink:href="#flag-ru"></use> 
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
```

### CSS + JS

При наведении на иконку появляется модальное окно с текстом.

Javascript нужен только для показа и убирания окна.

```js
var myicon = document.getElementById("svg1");
var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

myicon.addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
myicon.addEventListener("mouseout", hidePopup);

function showPopup(evt) {
  var iconPos = myicon.getBoundingClientRect();
  mypopup.style.left = (iconPos.right + 6) + "px";
  mypopup.style.top = (iconPos.top + 1) + "px";
  mypopup.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePopup(evt) {
  mypopup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #33333f;
}
#mypopup {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#mypopup::before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  width="40" height="24" viewBox="0 0 20 12"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<rect width="20" height="4" fill="white"/>
<rect y="4" width="20" height="4" fill="#001AFF"/>
<rect y="8" width="20" height="4" fill="#FF0000"/> 

</svg>

<div id="mypopup">
  <h3>Русскоязычная версия сайта</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
```